# prolog trace how to use

Tags: prolog, trace

How to go second step when trace prolog program? 
For example, I want to trace following simple program:

```
length1([],0).
length1([_X|Xs],N):- length1(Xs,N1), N is N1+1.
```

I trace program:

```
?- trace,length([1,2,3],N).
Call: (7) length([1, 2, 3], _G231) ? 
Exit: (7) length([1, 2, 3], 3) ? creep
N = 3.
```

But as we see, it immediately gives answer. But I thought it should be like `Call:(8) ... Call:(9) ...` What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at your goal, you used the built-in `length/2`, not your own `length1/2`. Built-ins usually can't be traced.

Answer (score 1):

after compling your file (example [length_program]. ) you need to write trace.
and then run your command, but I guess you are miss spelling the code. you have defined your pred as length1 so you need to put exactly length1 after your trace